# What is the difference between pscurvepoints and curvepnodes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, pstricks-add

What is the difference between `\pscurvepoints` (in `pstricks-add`) and `\curvepnodes` (in `pst-node`)?

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}%
\psLoop{25}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle*[linecolor=orange]{0.75}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=100]{0}{360}{rand 16 mod 90 div 1.50 add t PtoC}{P}
    %\pscurvepoints[plotpoints=100]{0}{360}{rand 16 mod 90 div 1.50 add t PtoC}{P}%==== option 2
    \def\points{}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}
    %\multido{\i=0+1}{\Ppointcount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}%==== option 2
    \expandafter\psccurve\points
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

When I enable the lines with `option 2` in comment and disable the corresponding lines, I just get a yolk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\pspolylineticks` refers to `\pscurvepoints`. That is the only difference.

Comment: What is the relationship between the `plotpoints` representing the number of vertices prepared by `pscurvepoints` and the last argument of `\pspolylineticks` representing the number of ticks? The documentation is confusing.

Comment: `\pspolylineticks` uses `\<NodePrefix>pointcount` which is only defined by `\pscurvepoints`

Comment: What is the relationship between `plotpoints=\<nodeprefix>pointcount` and the last argument of `\pspolylineticks`? In other words, why do we need to specify the last argument of `\pspolylineticks`?

Comment: plotpoints can be changed in the meantime by another command